# Microsoft !GERMAN! Azure Cloud - getting oauth2-proxy to work

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth2-proxy

I am trying to setup oauth2-proxy to authenticate against microsofts **german** azure cloud. It's quite a ride, but I got as far as being able to do the oauth handshake. However, I am getting an error when trying to receive user mail and name via the graph API.

I run the proxy within docker like this:

```
docker run -it  -p 8081:8081  \
    --name oauth2-proxy  --rm  \
    bitnami/oauth2-proxy:latest \
    --upstream=http://localhost:8080 \
    --provider=azure \
    --email-domain=homefully.de \
    --cookie-secret=super-secret-cookie \
    --client-id=$CLIENT_ID \
    --client-secret="$CLIENT_SECRET" \
    --http-address="0.0.0.0:8081" \
    --redirect-url="http://localhost:8081/oauth2/callback" \
    --login-url="https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/authorize" \
    --redeem-url="https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/token" \
    --resource="https://graph.microsoft.de" \
    --profile-url="https://graph.microsoft.de/me"
```

Right now it's stumbling upon the profile url (which is used to retrieve the identity of the user loggin in)

The log output is this:

```
2019/01/28 09:24:51 api.go:21: 400 GET https://graph.microsoft.de/me {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid request.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "1e55a321-87c2-4b85-96db-e80b2a5af1a3",
      "date": "2019-01-28T09:24:51"
    }
  }
}
```

I would REALLY appreciate suggestions about what I am doing wrong here? So far the documentation has not been really helpful to me. It seems that things are slighly different in the german azure cloud, but documentation is pretty thin on that. The fact that the azure docs only describe the US cloud where all urls are different (not in a very logical sense unfortunately) makes things a lot harder...

Best, 
Matthias

Answer (score 1):

the issue was that the profile url `https://graph.microsoft.de/me` was incorrect.

While `https://graph.microsoft.com/me` is valid for the US cloud, the german cloud requires the version embedded in the URL like this:

`https://graph.microsoft.de/v1.0/me`.

This worked for me:

```
docker run -it  -p 8081:8081  \
    --name oauth2-proxy  --rm  \
    bitnami/oauth2-proxy:latest \
    --upstream=http://localhost:8080 \
    --provider=azure \
    --email-domain=homefully.de \
    --cookie-secret=super-secret-cookie \
    --client-id=$CLIENT_ID \
    --client-secret="$CLIENT_SECRET" \
    --http-address="0.0.0.0:8081" \
    --redirect-url="http://localhost:8081/oauth2/callback" \
    --login-url="https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/authorize" \
    --redeem-url="https://login.microsoftonline.de/common/oauth2/token" \
    --resource="https://graph.microsoft.de" \
    --profile-url="https://graph.microsoft.de/v1.0/me"
```